# How does the class referred to by the OwinStartup attribute get called?

Tags: c#, startup, owin

After adding the nuget packages for OWIN if you add the attribute:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyProject.Startup))]
```

Then the class MyProject.Startup's method

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
```

gets called. How is this called? The only reference to OWIN in the web.config is an assembly binding redirect. There is no other reference in my project to a http module that would cause this attribute to be recognised. If I look at the stack trace I see the lines:

```
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll!Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(System.Web.HttpApplication context) Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(System.IntPtr appContext, System.Web.HttpContext context, System.Reflection.MethodInfo[] handlers)  Unknown
```

That shows that OWIN is registered as an event subscription with IIS, but how did this happen?Is this hard baked into the framework that it looks for an assembly reference?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the Configuration method and inspect the call stack when it gets hit, that should probably be illuminating.  I'd guess OWIN looks for this method in your assembly and invokes it using reflection

Comment: that is how I got the above partial call stack.

Comment: I think you'd find your answer with a disassembler.  I'd just go through the OWIN libraries and inspect the classes like OwinStartupAttribute and anything else you've referenced either in code or the web.config.

Comment: The complete call stack might provide extra clues.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ASP.NET 4 introduced [PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.preapplicationstartmethodattribute.aspx) Class. The primary use of this feature is to enable tasks that can’t be done within Application_Start because it’s too late. For example, registering build providers and adding assembly references. So, this attribute allows to have code run away early in the ASP.NET pipeline as an application starts up, even before Application_Start.

An use of this attribute would be:

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SomeClassLib.Initializer), "Initialize")]
```

The first parameter will be the type, and the second one, the method. That method will be public static void method with no arguments, like the code below:

```
public static class Initializer
{
  public static void Initialize() { 
    // Whatever can we do here?
  }
}
```

The [Katana source code](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/PreApplicationStart.cs) uses the PreApplicationStartMethod to hook into the application startup:

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(PreApplicationStart), "Initialize")]
```

This inidicates that will call the `Initialize()` method in `PreApplicationStart`:

```
public static class PreApplicationStart
{
    private const string TraceName = "Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.PreApplicationStart";

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers the OWIN request processing module.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        try
        {
            if (OwinBuilder.IsAutomaticAppStartupEnabled)
            {
                HttpApplication.RegisterModule(typeof(OwinHttpModule));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception1)
        {
            Exception exception = exception1;
            ITrace trace = TraceFactory.Create("Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.PreApplicationStart");
            trace.WriteError(Resources.Trace_RegisterModuleException, exception);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

In the line

```
HttpApplication.RegisterModule(typeof(OwinHttpModule));
```

OwinHttpModule takes over and goes into the OwinBuilder and OwinAppContext flows, which looks up the Startup class in your assembly to invoke the Configuration method.